# Highlight Specific text in each cell of a column if it matches with text of another column

Tags: excel, vba, highlight, conditional-formatting

I have 2 columns, Column B has some strings in each cell and Column C has a words in each cell. I want to highlight each words in column B that matches with column C. It is a table and has heading. I have tried so many codes but did not got desired result. Please help.

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQuZk.png)
[What I am expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPI4I.png)

Answer (score 1):

### Highlight Matching Substrings

[image]

```vb
Sub HighlightMatchingSubstrings()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A3"
    Const SRC_SPLIT_DELIMITER As String = " "
    Const SRC_COLOR As Long = vbRed
    
    Const LKP_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const LKP_FIRST_CELL As String = "B3"
    
    ' I just picked the ones I could think of!
    Dim Punctuation: Punctuation = Array(".", ",", "?", "!", ":", ";")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        srCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If srCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No source data in worksheet """ & sws.Name & """.", _
                vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    ' Reference the lookup range.
    
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Sheets(LKP_SHEET)
    
    Dim lrg As Range, lrCount As Long
    
    With lws.Range(LKP_FIRST_CELL)
        lrCount = lws.Cells(lws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If lrCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No lookup data in worksheet """ & lws.Name & """.", _
                vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set lrg = .Resize(lrCount)
    End With
    
    Dim dLen As Long: dLen = Len(SRC_SPLIT_DELIMITER)
    
    ' Clear existing font highlights.
    
    With srg.Font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Bold = False
    End With
    
    ' Highlight.
    
    Dim sCell As Range, SubStrings() As String, SubString, mIndex
    Dim n As Long, wLen As Long, pLen As Long, pStart As Long
    Dim sStr As String, Word As String
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        sStr = CStr(sCell.Value)
        If Len(sStr) > 0 Then
            pStart = 1
            SubStrings = Split(sStr, SRC_SPLIT_DELIMITER)
            For Each SubString In SubStrings
                wLen = Len(SubString)
                If wLen > 0 Then
                    Word = SubString
                    ' Remove trailing punctuation.
                    For n = wLen To 1 Step -1
                        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(Right(Word, 1), _
                                Punctuation, 0)) Then
                            Word = Left(Word, Len(Word) - 1)
                        Else
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next n
                    ' Match in lookup range and highlight.
                    mIndex = Application.Match(Word, lrg, 0)
                    If IsNumeric(mIndex) Then
                        pLen = Len(Word)
                        With sCell.Characters(pStart, pLen).Font
                            .Color = SRC_COLOR
                            .Bold = True
                        End With
                    End If
                End If
                pStart = pStart + wLen + dLen ' next substring position
            Next SubString
        End If
    Next sCell
     
    ' Inform.
     
    MsgBox "Matching substrings highlighted.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub HighlightMatchingValues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim startPos As Long, i As Long
        
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
    For i = 2 To lastRow
            
        If InStr(1, ws.Cells(i, "A").Value, ws.Cells(i, "B").Value) > 0 Then
            ' Apply red and bold formatting to the cell in column A
            startPos = InStr(1, ws.Cells(i, "A").Value, ws.Cells(i, "B").Value, vbTextCompare)
            ws.Cells(i, "A").Characters(startPos, Len(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value)).Font.Bold = True
            ws.Cells(i, "A").Characters(startPos, Len(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```